# Depending on the width size of the browser, the grid area may not fit

Tags: html, css, css-grid

If you stretch or shrink the width of your browser, there is an occasional margin in the bottom right corner.

[image]
[image]

How can I get rid of this white space?
In other words, I might say that I want the `card__bottom_right` class to be spread out all over the side.

Why is it sometimes a perfect fit and sometimes a gap?

This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      background: black;
    }

    .card {
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 800px;
      background: white;
      overflow: hidden;

      display: grid;
      grid-template:
        "card__title card__title card__title" 1fr
        "card__message card__message card__message" 1fr
        "card__bottom_left card__bottom_middle card__bottom_right" 1fr
        / 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }

    .card__title {
      padding-top: 16px;
      padding-left: 16px;
      grid-area: card__title;
    }

    .card__message {
      padding-top: 16px;
      padding-left: 16px;
      grid-area: card__message;
    }

    .card__bottom_left {
      background: pink;
      padding-left: 16px;
      grid-area: card__bottom_left;
    }

    .card__bottom_middle {
      background: pink;
      grid-area: card__bottom_middle;
    }

    .card__bottom_right {
      background: pink;
      grid-area: card__bottom_right;
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card__title">タイトル</div>
  <div class="card__message">メッセージ</div>
  <div class="card__bottom_left">1</div>
  <div class="card__bottom_middle">2</div>
  <div class="card__bottom_right">3</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

It looks like the above snippet may not be reproduced by running it in a stack overflow, though If you look at the Full page, it reproduce the problem.

I don't know if this is always the case, but I reproduced it when the browser width is 1085px.

Using: Chrome Version 85.0.4183.83 (Official Build) (64-bit)

---

It's hard to reproduce the above, so I've prepared a class that mimics the behavior of the browser(`wrap` class). I think it will be reproduced for sure.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      background: black;
    }

    .wrap {
      width: 1085px;
    }

    .card {
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 800px;
      background: white;
      overflow: hidden;

      display: grid;
      grid-template:
        "card__title card__title card__title" 1fr
        "card__message card__message card__message" 1fr
        "card__bottom_left card__bottom_middle card__bottom_right" 1fr
        / 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }

    .card__title {
      padding-top: 16px;
      padding-left: 16px;
      grid-area: card__title;
    }

    .card__message {
      padding-top: 16px;
      padding-left: 16px;
      grid-area: card__message;
    }

    .card__bottom_left {
      background: pink;
      padding-left: 16px;
      grid-area: card__bottom_left;
    }

    .card__bottom_middle {
      background: pink;
      grid-area: card__bottom_middle;
    }

    .card__bottom_right {
      background: pink;
      grid-area: card__bottom_right;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__title">タイトル</div>
      <div class="card__message">メッセージ</div>
      <div class="card__bottom_left">1</div>
      <div class="card__bottom_middle">2</div>
      <div class="card__bottom_right">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

An enlarged image of the above sunippe run is shown below. You can see a white line in the lower right corner.

[image]

**Summary of Questions**

- How to fit the grid area?
- Can you tell me why it doesn't fit if you can?

Comment: I can't seem to replicate it. When I have things like this, I would check to see if anything is to large in the other containers, margins, borders, etc. Is there a specific width this shows up? I also generally use flexbox over grid, but that is just opinion.

Comment: I add the browser width size to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could play by changing the background color of the elements for a better visual arrangement.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      background: black;
    }

    .card {
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 800px;
      
      overflow: hidden;

      display: grid;
      grid-template:
        "card__title card__title card__title" 1fr
        "card__message card__message card__message" 1fr
        "card__bottom_left card__bottom_middle card__bottom_right" 1fr
        / 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }

    .card__title {
      padding-top: 16px;
      padding-left: 16px;
      grid-area: card__title;
    }
    
    .card__title,
    .card__message {
      background: white;
    }

    .card__message {
      padding-top: 16px;
      padding-left: 16px;
      grid-area: card__message;
    }

    .card__bottom_left {
      background: pink;
      padding-left: 16px;
      grid-area: card__bottom_left;
    }

    .card__bottom_middle {
      background: pink;
      grid-area: card__bottom_middle;
    }

    .card__bottom_right {
      background: pink;
      grid-area: card__bottom_right;
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card__title">タイトル</div>
  <div class="card__message">メッセージ</div>
  <div class="card__bottom_left">1</div>
  <div class="card__bottom_middle">2</div>
  <div class="card__bottom_right">3</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you solve the problem by coloring each individual element instead of turning the whole card white?

Answer (score 0):

Add a reduced version of Eric Meyer's css reset.

Try the code below before the body css. Worked for me

[image: website screenshot]

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Source: https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Adapted thanks to Concordia Bootcamps

Comment: Did you try it in different browsers?